# Javascript x is not defined Object / array

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have an object and I am storing data as

```
{"anti-social-behaviour":43,"burglary":24,"other-theft":29,"shoplifting":2,"vehicle-crime":27,"violent-crime":34,"criminal-damage-arson":17,"public-order":2,"drugs":1,"robbery":3,"other-crime":3,"bicycle-theft":1}
```

I'm trying to interpret this data into a chart, google api. using the following

```
data.addRows([
  ['Drugs', crimes.drugs],
['bicycle-theft', crimes.bicycle-theft],
]);
```

crimes.drugs works fine however crimes.bicycle-theft is throwing

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: theft is not defined
at drawChart (crimes.js:126)
at <anonymous>
```

Comment: Can you set values like "public-order"? If yes, it may be an issue that the chart api interprets the dash as minus

Answer (score 4):

Since the property **`bicycle-theft`** has a **`-`** , you cannot access via **`dot operator`**, try this way,

```
data.addRows([
  ['Drugs', crimes.drugs],
  ['bicycle-theft', crimes['bicycle-theft']],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access properties like that way `(crimes.bicycle-theft`) when have '-' symbol. You should write `crimes["bicycle-theft"]`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to access properties: dot notation and bracket notation.

When using dot notation, your property must be a valid JavaScript identifier.

When using bracket notation, the string provided does not have to be a valid identifier.

Here 'bicycle-theft' is not a valid identifier due to '-'.

Documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Answer (score 0):

rather than hard-code the array,
use --> `Object.keys` -- to build the rows...

```
Object.keys(objData).forEach(function (key) {
  data.addRow([
    key,
    objData[key]
  ]);
});
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {

  var objData = {"anti-social-behaviour":43,"burglary":24,"other-theft":29,"shoplifting":2,"vehicle-crime":27,"violent-crime":34,"criminal-damage-arson":17,"public-order":2,"drugs":1,"robbery":3,"other-crime":3,"bicycle-theft":1};

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Crime');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Occurrences');

  Object.keys(objData).forEach(function (key) {
    data.addRow([
      key,
      objData[key]
    ]);
  });

  data.sort([{column: 1, desc: true}]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {
    chartArea: {
      bottom: 24,
      height: '100%',
      left: 176,
      right: 96,
      top: 36,
      width: '100%'
    },
    height: 400,
    legend: {
      alignment: 'end',
      position: 'top'
    },
    title: 'Crime',
    width: '100%'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```